# Is there an exact solution for tan(36) using origami from a unit square?

Tags: trigonometry, origami

This question is more for chagrins and curiosity than anything else: Is there a way to use origami to construct the tangent of 36 degrees (~0.7265425)? 
I've come up with the image below, which is accurate to about 5 decimal places (the exact decimal eludes me at the moment), but I'd like something closer if it exists. 

[image: An almost-exact solution.] The vertical red line on the right is at x = ~0.7265403. 

As I said, the question is mostly for chagrins (as the method above is close enough in practice), but I'd appreciate any more creative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form a [pentagon base](http://www.origami-instructions.com/origami-pentagon-base.html).  All ten resulting central angles are 36 degrees.  Taking the short radial fold to have length $1$, the half-edge has length $\tan(36 ^\circ)$.  (That is, you have ten right triangles with adjacent $1$ and opposite $\tan(36 ^\circ)$.)

So start with this step of the [pentagon base](http://www.inthekitchenwithmum.com/2015/01/how-to-fold-an-origami-pentagon/).

[image: pentagon base, partially completed to produce four 36 degree angles on the horizontal baseline]

Now unfold to the beginning.  Observe that there is a central vertex with four 36 degree angles to its right.  The two right triangles sharing a leg along the first bisection fold are what we want to project to an edge.  Extend either hypotenuse all the way across the paper.  (This extension almost auto-folds for me.  You have the two long legs of the adjacent right triangles to guide this fold.)  Taking the extended hypotenuse as a unaxial base, construct a hinge passing through a (either) corner.  (The extended hypotenuse, the axis for this hinge, is indicated with pink arrows in the following diagram.)

[image: The paper with the perpendicular fold, across the extended hypotenuse, through a corner. The axis is indicated with pinkish arrows and the constructed point is indicated with a light blue arrow.]

The hinge meets the edge opposite the corner at the desired point (indicated by the light blue arrow).

Note that the foreground flap is a $36^\circ \text{-} 54^\circ \text{-} 90^\circ$ triangle, as desired.  Why?  The right triangle we started with has legs parallel to the edges of the paper.  Any perpendicular to its hypotenuse meets an edge at either $36^\circ$ or $54^\circ$.  We just arranged for the hinge to hit one of the two sides forming a $54^\circ$ angle.

Comment: The question asks to **start** from a unit square, though, so I don't think you're allowed to just set the length of the short radial fold to have length $1$.

Comment: @YiFan : As is common, the *question* does not ask this.  The *title* does.  So much time is wasted on this site due to this variety of mismatch.  As per usual, we will have to wait for the OP to resolve which is normative.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I'm looking for a way to find tan(36) in relation to the edge of a unit square--in other words, find the point (0.7265425, 0) with the bottom left corner of the square at the origin.

Comment: @YiFan : ... and ... done.